# how to insert search view in toolbar?

Tags: android, insert, icons, toolbar, searchview

A few lines of the logcat

```
11-26 01:14:04.752 16902-16902/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve         virtual method 3268: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performOptionsMenuClosed     (Landroid/view/Menu;)V
11-26 01:14:04.752 16902-16902/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x04ac
11-26 01:14:07.315 16902-16902/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
11-26 01:14:08.896 16902-16902/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
11-26 01:14:08.936 16902-16902/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-26 01:14:08.936 16902-16902/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
```

2-Screenshot of the app on my phone.

[image: screenshot of the app on my phoen]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions written in English. http://forum.frandroid.com/forum/7-d%C3%A9veloppement/ offers support in French. (Google Translate: Stack Overflow est pour les questions écrites en anglais. http://forum.frandroid.com/forum/7-d%C3%A9veloppement/ offre un support en français.)

Comment: I understood your remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XML**

I - Create a searchable configuration in a `searchable.xml` saved in res/xml directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

II - Declare your searchable activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity">  
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
              android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

III- Declare your SearchView inside any `layout.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  
   android:id="@+id/search"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**STYLING**

I. Declare custom styles in your `styles.xml` file.

```
<style name="SearchViewTheme" >  
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/amber500</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/green500</item>
</style>
```

II. Apply this style

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_library"
    app:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"/>
```

**JAVA**

I- Setting up the SearchView in the `OnCreate` method

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);  
// Sets searchable configuration defined in searchable.xml for this SearchView
SearchManager searchManager =  
    (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

II- Receiving search query

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);  
// Sets searchable configuration defined in searchable.xml for this SearchView
SearchManager searchManager =  
    (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

III- Listening to the user inputs (getting inputs)

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {  
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    searchFor(query);
    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    filterSearchFor(query);
    return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: think you,I test this

Comment: Please find the SearchActivity file what it contains?

Comment: you mean the JAVA part ?

Comment: yes SearchActivity.java

Comment: check the updated answer, JAVA coding added

Comment: Thank you very much, I test.If you like to know it.My final application should be a newspaper consultation application according to the flow so if you have other posts, it will help me a lot.

Comment: Here is the SearchActivity.java file but there are two errors: Cannot resolve method 'searchFor and filterSearchFor(java.lang.string)'.

Comment: those are separate java classes the are not predefined methode

Comment: I am unhappy my app does not run anymore. And yet it compiles without error.

Comment: i posted event log

Comment: are testing on a real device or an emulator ?

Comment: I can not post all the contents of the logcat. I take how many lines?

Comment: you need to post the LogCat so I can help you fix the errors otherwise I will not be able to help you

Comment: Samsung GT-19192 Android 4.4.4, API 19

Comment: I can also send you the screenshot on my phone

Comment: Ok send the screenshot

Comment: @ladougol i  posted