# Fragment Activity with Menu in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-toolbar, searchview

I have a fragment activity with Custom Toolbar as seen below .

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:weightSum="10">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="TEST"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorFontTitle"
                            android:textSize="19sp"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <SearchView
                            android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:gravity="right" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarImg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Below that I have viewpager and Tab layout structure

I need to add menu item with SearchView menu at the end of toolbar but seems not visible in my Fragment .

So I added SearchView in Toolbar itself ,but it overlaps with Text and does not hide it as in menu .
How can I overcome it in Fragment.

Comment: There are too many `LinearLayout` - `RelativeLayout`s in there. This isn't a good approach. Couldn't you use a 3rd-party library which has all this and you won't be worried about menus and etc?

Comment: ok ...forget the layout .. simple ... how can i have searchview menu in fragmentactivity toolbar

Comment: `SearchView` menu or just `SearchView`? Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811767/how-to-insert-search-view-in-toolbar